# Iterating an <ul> list using MooTools

Tags: arrays, mootools, each, loops

I am trying to iterate the list below:

```
<ul>
  <li class="tab">Tab 1</li>
  <li class="tab">Tab 2</li>
  <li class="tab">Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

Using the following MooTools script:

```
$$('ul').getElements().each(function(el,i) {
    alert(i);
});
```

I only see "0" appear on the screen where as I'm expecting "0", "1", "2". Can any one explain this?

Comment: are people still choosing MooTools over jQuery? </sarcasm> ;)

Comment: Indeed we are - nothing wrong with it at all. :)

Answer (score 2):

`$$('ul')` returns a list of `ul` elements. If you then call `getElements` on that list, you need to specify a tag name. This will get you a list of a list of `li` elements: `[[li, li, li]]`.
So, if you want to iterate over your `li` elements, you can do the following:

```
 $$('ul').getElements('li')[0].each(function (el, i) { alert(i); });
```

or:

```
$$('ul li').each(function(li, index){
    // faster. 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `$$` iterate through the entire DOM? Not knowing the context of @Ben's code, I can't say for certain, but I'd almost always give the `ul` an `id` property and select for it via `document.id`, or using `.getElement()` from a containing parent element.

Comment: $$ does not iterate through the entire dom as such, not always - eg. `$$('#id ul li')` will be faster than `document.id('id').getElements('ul li')` as well. in his case, yes, it will get all ul li combos from the entire dom. QSA deals with that pretty good. getElementsByTagName fallback. i assume it's pseudo code and he actually anchors...